# Error handling in go, which file and line?

Tags: go

I did not find a better way to show error details in long form.

```
log.SetFlags(log.Llongfile)
```

I am particularly interested which file and line error happened. Is it any way to set long format application wide rather than add to every function?

Comment: That is how you set it for the default logger.  What do you mean by "add to every function"?

Comment: Thank you, Jim. I have to start every function with that settings:

       func GetSettings(path string) string {
 log.SetFlags(log.Llongfile)
 f, err := os.Open("config.json")
 if err != nil {
  log.Fatal(err)
 }

Comment: and if I log.fatal in main - I got only short description

Comment: I don't understand. `log.SetFlags` sets the flags for the default output from the `log` package. If you want that set for all calls to the log package functions, set it once before you call any of those functions.

Comment: sorry, I am a go beginner :-). when I run it in main - first line, it works only for main. so any other package shows short form. Probably setting this flag and then passing logger to every package will work. But is it any more elegant solution?

Comment: Setting it once in main will affect _any_ package that uses the default logger (unless those packages later change it back). There's nothing you can do to globally affect packages that don't use the default logger called by the log package functions.

Comment: Yes, Jim. It does work. I mess something up earlier. THANK YOU. Would be happy to add Star to you if you can answer me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to consider [`gin`](https://github.com/codegangsta/gin) to watch and tells you where errors happened after build.

Comment: OMG, Mr Sigit. That's exactly what I needed. My whole-heart appreciation of your help.